# Read file in Documents folder using CeateFile2 from Unit test library for WindowsStoreApp

Tags: unit-testing, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am writing a Unit Test library (for windows store app) . I need to read a bin file as part of starting test case . i have provided capabilities in my appmanifest of my unit test library to read .bin files in documents folder . I am Using CreateFile2 function for opening the file in read mode .

But the CreateFile2 function is failing with invalid handle and GetLastError() is returning AccessDenied .

Cant we use CreateFile2 function ? The documentation says it is supported in windowsstore Apps . Or cant we read documents folder using this CreateFile API ?Else what is the alternate loaction to place the bin file , if i want to use on CreateFile2 function and not the winRT API ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The only locations I've been able to access successfully with CreateFile2 and other legacy functions are the app bundle and the ApplicationData localFolder.

Comment: yes..even for me it is the same behavior .. i am able to acces the file when copied the file to LocalFolder ..